# Explain the following algorithm

Tags: discrete-mathematics, algorithms, computational-complexity

Below is the algorithm I am working with. I am to walk through the example (2,5) explaining what the algorithm does and what its worst-case runtime will be

```
function Do-something(a,b)
   if b = 0 then
      return 1
   else if b is even then
      x <- Do-something(a,b/2)
      return x * x
   else if b is odd then
      x <- Do-something(a,(b-1)/2)
      return x * x * a
   end if
end function
```

Initially looking at the function I am confused as to if it will ever output anything other than 1 or a. Here is how I see (2,5) working.

(2,5) is entered, then is sent to b being odd. x is set to so-something(2,2)

(2,2) is entered and sent to even. x is set to DO-something(2,1)

(2,1) is entered and sent to odd. x is set to do_something(2,0)

Finally (2,0) is entered and 1 is returned. Now we are sent back to the original, in which was it returned is x * x * a. Or 1 * 1 * 2.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a recursive function. Every time it calls itself, it creates a new instance of all variables. So the major mistake in your run-thru is treating all occurrences of "$x$" as the same $x$, while in fact they are all different.

Here is how it's actually going to work on the input $(2,5)$.

**Instance 1.** $(2,5)$ is entered. Then it's sent to $b_1=5$ being odd. $x_1$ is set to $\operatorname{DoSomething}(2,2)$, which creates a new instance of the function and its variables.

**Instance 2.** $(2,2)$ is entered. Then it's sent to $b_2=2$ being even. $x_2$ is set to $\operatorname{DoSomething}(2,1)$, which creates a new instance of the function and its variables.

**Instance 3.** $(2,1)$ is entered. Then it's sent to $b_3=1$ being odd. $x_3$ is set to $\operatorname{DoSomething}(2,0)$, which creates a new instance of the function and its variables.

**Instance 4.** Finally (except it isn't final yet), $(2,0)$ is entered and $1$ is returned. Returned where? That's where you made a mistake. It's returned back to $x_3=\operatorname{DoSomething}(2,0)=1$ of Instance 3.

**Back to Instance 3**. We're in the "$b$ is odd" case, and $x=x_3=1$. So this function returns $x\cdot x\cdot a=x_3\cdot x_3\cdot a=1\cdot1\cdot2=2$. And to where is this returned? It's returned back to $x_2=\operatorname{DoSomething}(2,1)=2$ of Instance 2.

**Back to Instance 2**. We're in the "$b$ is even" case, and $x=x_2=2$. So this function returns $x\cdot x=x_2\cdot x_2=2\cdot2=4$. And to where is this returned? It's returned back to $x_1=\operatorname{DoSomething}(2,2)=4$ of Instance 1.

**Back to Instance 1**. We're in the "$b$ is odd" case, and $x=x_1=4$. So this function returns … (you fill it in now). And since this was the original call of the function, this is the final output.

I hope this will help you see what this function actualy does.

Comment: I see! This makes sense. Knowing what it does with input now, I am curious about what the output is telling you. It isn't obvious to me right away what the output means, but I understand how to get it.

Comment: @lex320: Note that, as part of this solution, we've established that $\operatorname{DoSomething}(2,0)=1$, $\operatorname{DoSomething}(2,1)=2$, $\operatorname{DoSomething}(2,2)=4$ (I had a typo there originally, but I've fixed it now), and $\operatorname{DoSomething}(2,5)=\ldots$. Also, for more observations, run  $\operatorname{DoSomething}(2,4)=\ldots$. If you look at all these values, you should notice a pattern to tell you what the function does.